# Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR using GPU on PyAgender

Tags: python, tensorflow

Sample code runs fine with CUDNN but using code installed with pip returns Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR.

I am using Tensorflow 1.12, CUDA 10.0 and CUDNN 7.4.1 compiled with GPU 2080 (x2)

This is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I also use venv. Everything is done in venv using Python 3.5.2.

I am trying to use Py-Agender from https://pypi.org/project/py-agender/

After compiling CUDA with GPU flags and successfully verifying that it works, I tried:
`enter code here`pip3 install py-agender.

Running it then causes an internal CUDNN error.

I have removed ~/.nv as suggested in other replies and it did not help

I have also confirmed that CuDNN does in fact see and can use GPUs:

```
print(device_lib.list_local_devices()) returns:

2019-01-03 09:31:30.353768: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-01-03 09:31:30.354169: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce RTX 2080 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.8
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
```

... so we at least something works!

b. mNIST sample runs and returns values as expected.

The part of code is as follows:

```
agender = PyAgender() 

def get_gender(value) :
    if value > 0.5:
        return 'female'
    else :
        return 'male'

input_dir = sys.argv[1]

directories = os.listdir(input_dir)

if len(directories):
    for video in directories:
        files = glob.glob(input_dir + video + '/*')

        if len(files):
            for file_path in files:

                filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))
                faces = agender.detect_genders_ages(cv2.imread(file_path))
```

The code worked fine with Tensorflow compiled with CPU only. With GPU, the full error is:

```
$ python age-gender.py ./frames/part1/

Using TensorFlow backend.
- Began to analyze the age and gender 
2019-01-03 09:44:24.229618: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-01-03 09:44:24.230019: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce RTX 2080 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.8
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 totalMemory: 7.76GiB freeMemory: 7.62GiB
2019-01-03 09:44:24.302145: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] su
ccessful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-01-03 09:44:24.302602: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found
 device 1 with properties:name: GeForce RTX 2080 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.8 pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0 totalMemory: 7.77GiB freeMemory: 7.62GiB
2019-01-03 09:44:24.302625: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Addin
g visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2019-01-03 09:44:24.665465: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device
 interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-01-03 09:44:24.665492: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 1
2019-01-03 09:44:24.665499: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N Y
2019-01-03 09:44:24.665504: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 1:   Y N
2019-01-03 09:44:24.665749: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7335 MB memory) ->
 physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2019-01-03 09:44:24.666056: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 7338 MB memory) ->
 physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce RTX 2080, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2019-01-03 09:44:25S :: Filename: ./frames/part1/2017/658.jpg
2019-01-03 09:44:25S :: Filename:  ./frames/part1/2017/698.jpg
2019-01-03 09:44:25S :: Filename:  ./frames/part1/2017/746.jpg 
2019-01-03 09:44:25S :: Filename:  ./frames/part1/2017/371.jpg 
2019-01-03 09:44:25S :: Filename:  ./frames/part1/2017/218.jpg 
2019-01-03 09:44:25S :: Filename:  ./frames/part1/2017/860.jpg 
2019-01-03 09:44:26.702699: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:373] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2019-01-03 09:44:26.709821: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:373] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "age-gender.py", line 50, in <module>
    faces = agender.detect_genders_ages(cv2.imread(file_path))
  File "/home/sv/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyagender/pyagender.py", line 56, in detect_genders_ages
    height=face['height'])
  File "/home/sv/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyagender/pyagender.py", line 82, in gender_age
    result = self.resnet.predict(np.array([test_img]))
  File "/opt/inta/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1169, in predict
    steps=steps)
  File "/opt/inta/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 294, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/opt/inta/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "/opt/inta/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "/opt/inta/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/opt/inta/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
         [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@batch_normalization_1/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch"], data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](conv2d_1/convolution-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer, conv2d_1/kernel/read)]]
```

Comment: This might be similar to the issue raised here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24496